# Generating Component without spec.ts file in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-components, angular-schematics

Is there a way to get rid of the spec.ts file in Angular 2+, whenever I create a new component. I know this is for testing purpose but what if I don't need it.

May be there is some setting to disable this specific testing file.

Comment: When you create a new component with Angular CLI?

Comment: yes exactly when we generate component from Angular cli.

Comment: Angular 7/8 CLI  its  --skipTests=true|false

Answer (score 296, accepted):

**Updated for Angular >=8 CLI**

For one component use the following command:

```
ng generate component --skip-tests=true component-name
```

For a single project, change or add the following in your `angular.json`:

```
{ 
  "projects": {
    "{PROJECT_NAME}": {
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "skipTests": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For a global setting for all your projects, change or add the following in your `angular.json`:

```
{ 
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "skipTests": true
    }
  }
}
```

Or by using the command line

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.skipTests true
```

---

**< Angular 8**

Inside your `angular-cli.json` set the spec.component parameter to `false`:

```
{
   ...
   "defaults" : {
       ...
       "spec": {
           ...
           "component": false
       }
   }
}
```

or use the `--spec=false` option during creation

```
ng generate component --spec=false component-name
```

Comment: @Pierre - What about if I dont want folder too

Comment: It works but there is no "spec" inside defaults object so maybe it's updated by Angular on later version.
The new solution should be like that"defaults": {
    "class": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "component": {
      "spec": false
    }
  }

Comment: Option `spec` is deprecated: Use `skipTests` instead

Comment: Is there any way to stop generating this spec.ts file for the whole project ?

Comment: @Damika isn't that covered in the beginning of my answer?

Comment: @PoulKruijt Ah yeah I can understand now ; changing the angular.json file, Thank you. Is this way valid for angular-cli 13 ?

Comment: Don't forget @schematics/angular:service if you want to skip it for services too.

Answer (score 19):

For Angular 6

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular.component.spec false
```

Answer (score 13):

For Angular 7 and higher this will work :

```
ng generate component componentname --skipTests
```

or 
    `ng generate component componentname --skipTests=true`

Answer (score 13):

## Latest Angular 9 Compatible

#### CLI Command

```
ng generate component your-component-name --skipTests=true
```

*or* using the alias `s` instead of `--skipTests`

```
ng generate component your-component-name -s=true
```

---

#### Modifying `angular.json` to avoid using above CLI command always

Copy the below snippet to the root of a specific project (`projects.your-project-name`) in its `angular.json`.

*The below will ensure `.spec` files are not created for **Components**, **Class**, **Directives**, **Pipe** and **Service** with the `ng generate` command.* You may choose the ones as per requirement.

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "your-project-name": {
      ...
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:class": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
          "skipTests": true
        }
      },
    ...
}
```

PS: The `--spec=false` option is now deprecated and will not work

Comment: The `s` should be capital here. Small s creates inline styles (no external scss file).

`ng generate component your-component-name -S=true`

Comment: I tried the -S option and got an unknown comment.  -s didn't prevent the spec file but the css file. I am using version 12.

Comment: Actually, I meant "unknown option" not "unknown comment"

Answer (score 11):

When using angular-cli there is a bunch of options to pass. To generate a new component without tests, you can simply add `--spec=false` like so:

```
ng generate component --spec=false my-component
```

There is also an option in the angular-cli.json for which types you want to enable specs by default, where you can modify the behaviour:

```
"defaults": {
  "spec": {
    "class": false,
    "component": true,
    "directive": true,
    "module": false,
    "pipe": true,
    "service": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working in angular cli version 11

Answer (score 11):

For **angular 6+** Simply run this command:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular.component.spec false
```

**OR**

just add this in your angular.json file and you're good to go

```
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular": {
      "component": {
        "spec": false
      }
    }
  }
```

**NOTE: before pasting this check for conflicts, hope it helps**

Comment: Updated my angular.json as per above in my Angular 7.4 project and all good.

Answer (score 5):

In recent Angular versions you can configure the cli generator to disable the creation of spec file for components and services in `angular-cli.json` as follows:

```
"defaults": {
    "component": { "spec": false },
    "service": { "spec": false },
    ...
}
```

You can add extra lines to disable specs also for guards and classes and so on.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I added extra explanation to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

simply try this one.
this is working

```
ng g c component_name --spec false
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a command for disabling Angular generate "spec" files by default

```
ng set defaults.class.spec=false
ng set defaults.component.spec=false
```

**UPDATE:** For Angular 6

`ng config schematics.@schematics/angular.component.spec false`

Comment: Deprecated in angular 6

Answer (score 4):

Simply create Component with this simple command in Angular 7

```
ng g c component-name --spec false
```

or if really dont want to include it in any component simply update angular.json

```
"@schematics/angular": {
  "component": {
    "spec": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Angular 8: `ng generate component mycomponent --skipTests=false`

Answer (score 3):

from angular version 11, use the below command

```
ng generate component "path/componentname" --skip-tests=true
```

or simply

```
ng g c "path/componentname" --skip-tests
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ng g c component-name --spec false
```

Answer (score 2):

here what it is for angular 9

```
ng g class models\user --skip-tests true
```

it will not generate spec.ts files.

Answer (score 2):

`--spec` will no longer work. Use  `--skip-tests`  instead.

You will see all the options with following command:

```
ng g c --help
```

Answer (score 2):

For Angular 10+ - For a global setting for all your projects.

1. Go to angular.json file
2. In the "schematics" field add:

   ```
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "skipTests": true
    },
   ```

** It's possible also for services, guards, etc...

```
    "@schematics/angular:service": {
      "skipTests": true
    },
    "@schematics/angular:guard": {
      "skipTests": true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [fix #156](https://github.com/DevIntent/angular-cli/commit/fbdbedbfc3b7833e253efe8b32aafca6fc99ece7) you can create a component without spec file by using

```
ng generate component my-comp --nospec
```

Answer (score 1):

For angular 6 add this in angular.json inside `"schematics":{}` :

```
"@schematics/angular": {
  "component": {
    "spec": false
  }
}
```

**OR**

as Franklin Pious sugested, run this command:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular.component.spec false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to skip spec file for specific component.

**New version:**

```
ng generate component "componentName" --skipTests
```

*Example*

```
ng generate component recipe-list --skipTests
```

**Old version :**

```
ng generate component "componentName" --spec false
```

*Example*

```
ng generate component recipe-list --spec false
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to do. While creating the component add

> --skipTests=true

```
ng generate component --skipTests=true componentName
```

Or

```
ng g c --skipTests=true componentName
```

Answer (score 1):

For angular 8+ you just need to add

> --skipTests=true

in the end

```
ng g c component-name --skipTests=true
```

g is abbreviated to generate.
c is abbreviated to component

you can also use

```
ng generate component component-name --skipTests=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Reply: Generating Component without spec.ts file in Angular 2+

**ng g c ComponentName --skip-tests true**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This seems right, but too much like answers already given, so in the future  you may wish to check for duplication. For instance, if the case of ComponentName needs to be exact, that is very good information.

Answer (score 1):

in your project go into **angular.json** file and add **spec - false** in schematics feild

save and restart your project
now you can create all component without spec file

```
 "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "style": "scss",
                    "spec": false
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Angular 16

Generate Component without spec.ts file I have to use the following command.

```
ng g c component-name --skip-tests
```

You can use the CLI help to see the what are the available options

```
 ng g c --help
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command when you create your component

```
ng g c component-name --spec false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use also the following command if you want to skip your spec.ts file:

`ng g c try-it --skipTests=true`

where

`g c` => generate component , 
`try-it` => component name , 
`--skipTest=true` => == `-- spec false`.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this bit of information because I found myself struggling with the same issue and could not fix it by using the current answer(s), plus I did not want to make the changes on the `angular-cli.json` file. It appears the recent version of Angular CLI `--spec=false` is depreciated and therefore no longer works, use `--skipTests` instead.

Test on:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.1
Node: 12.16.1
OS: win32 x64
```

Your command with then be:
`ng g c mycomponent --skipTests` 
instead of
`ng g c mycomponent --spec=false`

**PS**: Always test your commands using the `--dry-run` option to test your output.

Answer (score 0):

## When using:

- Angular CLI: 10.0.3
- Node: 12.16.3
- Angular: 10.0.4

You have to use "--skip-tests true" when generating component.
(Note: you can get the above version info by trying "ng v" or "ng -v" in the terminal).

You can get the complete list of switches for "ng g c (short for ng generate component)" using "ng g c --help".

Alternatively you can add a component manually. To do this, make a new folder by right clicking the /src/app folder of your project. After creating the folder, right click on it to add one or more files such as mycomp.component.html and mycomp.component.ts.
Adding mycomp.component.ts is the minimum required list for a component, as you can add inline css and html to your .ts file.

### Example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

@Component ({
selector: 'app-mycomp',
template: '`<p> Hello Angular </p>`'
})

export class MyComp {}

*Import and Register MyComp in app.module.ts declarations list, and add it to app.component.html or some other template, using selector (`<app-mycomp></app-mycomp`>*

Answer (score 0):

**Angular < 8**
`$ ng g component component-name --spec=false`

**Angular > 8** 
`$ ng g component component-name --skipTests=false --flat`

```
   $ ng g component employee/listEmployees --skipTests=false --flat
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me for `angular 11`

```
ng g c posts/new-component --module app --skip-tests
```

**Note:**

name of component should be like this : `new-component` or `newComponent`.

generate for specific follder : `dir/new-component`

add `new-component` to the `app.module.ts` : `--module app`

use just `--skip-tests` in command for generating Component without `spec.ts` file

Answer (score 0):

And now in Angular 16 according to the Angular official documentation, it is:

```
ng g c [component name] --skip-tests=true
```

Answer (score 0):

### command prompt:

D:\Angular\project 1>ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.skipTests true

### angular.json:

in angular.json file we can add the below line then (___.component.spec.ts) this files never generates when we creating.

"schematics": {
"@schematics/angular:component": {
"skipTests": true
}
},

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

> For Angular 9 you can use

`ng g c "componentName" --spec=false`

> to generate component without spec file