# Angular CLI command issue: "Unknown option: '--spec'"

Tags: angular, command, angular-cli

I am running this command:

`C:\Users\Murali\my-first-app>ng g c abcde5 --dry-run -t -s --spec=false`

I am receiving the following error:

`Unknown option: '--spec'`

How can I correct my command to avoid this?

Answer (score 46):

You can find all options [here](https://angular.io/cli/generate#component). Answering you question replace `--spec=false` by `--skip-tests`. If it won't working please provide the AngularCLI version

Comment: just --skipTests option (without '=true') works well too

Answer (score 11):

You can also use   `--skip-tests`  flag to skip generating .spec files. 
 For more detail, you can use   `ng g c --help`, this will give you further details

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
--spec=false
```

use

```
--skip-tests
```

Don't use `--skipTests=true` because

> Support for camel case arguments has been deprecated and will be removed in a future major version.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Angular CLI version 3, replace

```
--spec=false
```

with

```
--skipTests=true
```

Answer (score 2):

```bash
ng generate component componenetname --skipTests=true --inlineStyle=true
```

was replaced by

```bash
ng generate component componenetname --skip-tests --inline-style
```

in angular CLI 14

Answer (score 1):

Use rather than `--sepc false` :

```
--skip-tests
```

In the old version of angular, it's was working right but in the new version this not working with me anymore.

Answer (score 0):

ng g c componentname --skipTests true

In the newer version of Angular CLI --spec is replaced with --skipTests.

This is working at my site.

Answer (score 0):

With **Angular >= 8** you can use:

```
ng g c component-name --skip-tests --dry-run -s -t
```

OR

You can edit `angular.json` to set your global setting to use `--skip-tests` automatically without having to add it as a flag each time you generate a component with the CLI, by adding the `skipTests` parameter with value `true` ie:

```
{ 
  "projects": {
    "<PROJECT_NAME>": {
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "skipTests": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To set this globally run:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.skipTests true
```

Then, with this config above you can simply use:

```
ng g c component-name --dry-run -s -t
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40990424/7848529) for further details. Also, for a list of all available options try:

```
ng g c --help
```