# Generating component without spec.ts in Angular within nx workspace

Tags: angular, angular-components, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I want to do it for the entire project, but unlike an Angular CLI project, there is no `angular.json` file, only a `project.json` one.

So, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40990424/6188947), I could add some config somewhere to enable the skipTests property, but I tried in the `project.json` with no success, so how can I do it ?

Note : I use nx version 15.8.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify defaults in *nx.json*:

```
{
  ...
  "generators": {
    ...
    "@nx/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss",
      "standalone": true,
      "changeDetection": "OnPush",
      "displayBlock": true,
      "flat": true,
      "inlineStyle": true,
      "inlineTemplate": true,
      "skipTests": true
    },
    ...
```

If you use Nx Console (I recommend) then these will also be used.

Comment: I don't know why I looked at the project.json but not the nx.json...Well, it worked, thanks !